# How to obtain the SonarQube project URL in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have integrated SonarQube with Jenkins and it's working fine. Now I need to obtain the SonarQube project URL from the pipeline. I checked the documentation and there's no reference to that. Below are the pipeline stages corresponding to SonarQube analysis and quality gate.

```
stage('SonarQube Analysis'){
    dir('.tmp'){
        withSonarQubeEnv('dev2-sonarqube') {
            withMaven(maven:'maven 3.5.3') {
                sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar'
            }
        } // SonarQube taskId is automatically attached to the pipeline context
    }
}

stage("Quality Gate"){

    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
        def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
            // error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
            print "Quality Gate failed, but building is allowed for now"

            // send to email
            recipientList = committers.concat(env.tl_email)
            emailext (
                subject: "$env.JOB_NAME - Build #$env.BUILD_NUMBER - ${qg.status}",
                body: '''${SCRIPT,template="qg-fail.template"}''',
                to: "${recipientList}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass the SonarQube project URL to the quality fail email so the developers can directly jump to the relevant project from the mail. Any idea how can I obtain the SonarQube project URL in the pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

You can use env var `SONAR_HOST_URL` inside the sonar block, like this:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('my-sonar') {
  echo '${env.SONAR_HOST_URL}'
  // my-sonar.example.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The project URL depends only on the project key. If you know the project key and the host of your SonarQube instance, then something along the lines of

ProjectURL = host + "/dashboard?id=" + ProjectID

could work.

When you call "sonar:sonar", you are actually referencing the sonar.properties file where you typically define your project key so I don't know of any way to programatically get the project key without reading it in from the this file. I would recommend saving your project key/host in the Jenkins file and forming the URL of the project then placing it in the email body.